# Having fields be conditionally required in rails model?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails app for a moving company.  I am working on a way for leads to enter data that will be submitted.  There is a lot of very straight forward information (name, email, phone, etc.) but they also need to enter an origin Address, Zip code, city, state and country and same for a destination.  I want the State box to be a select box with a list of states/provinces, but ONLY if the country is the United States or Canada.  If the country is not the United States or Canada, the box will disappear/they will not be able to submit a value.  Is this possible in rails, or is this more likely something I would use jquery for?  Would it be implemented in the model, controller or view (it seems like the model for the validation, and the view for the presentation of the box, but I'm not sure)?

I'm still kinda new to rails, so I'm sorry if this should be a simple answer.  I'm using rails 4 for this app.

Comment: You can handle that with a combination of jQuery and ActiveRecord validation. For the jQuery you want a listener on country and have it show/hide State based on the selection. In the model, validations can be conditional. It can require the presence of State if the Country is the United States.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be on the right track! The hiding/showing of the `states/provinces` box would be handled by jQuery. You could also use an ActiveRecord validation in your model to ensure that the `state` field is blank if the country isn't USA or Canada:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :state, presence: false, unless: Proc.new { |m| m.country.in?["USA", "Canada"] }
end
```

conversely:

```
validates :state, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |m| m.country.in?["USA", "Canada"] }
```

You can learn more about custom validations at the [RailsGuides page for Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless). Section 5 talks about conditional validations using custom methods and procs. Section 6 talks about even more powerful custom validations but I doubt you need to go that far here.

Answer (score 1):

To add to `sixty4bit`'s answer (which I upvoted), you should put your validations into Rails' backend, only handling the response with JS.

---

[Convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) calls for you to use as much of the inbuilt framework functionality as you can; when you start configuring validations etc through JQuery, you end up with code all over the place, often leading to massive bloat (repetition of code etc).

Rails' validation system is very good -- you can send any set of params through your controller and the model will accept/reject depending on whether the data fits the validations.

Thus, I would definitely suggest putting a [`validator`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in your model; I'd do it slightly differently than `sixty4bit`'s answer ([you can use strings with `if`/`unless`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless)):

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :state, inclusion: { in: %w(usa canada),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid state" }, unless: "state.blank?"
end
```

--

> it seems like the model for the validation, and the view for the presentation of the box

In addition to the model validation (which is for the params alone), you'd need some sort of front-end mechanism to deal with the blanking-out of the select box.

This can be done relatively simply:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select#state", function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() != "USA") || ($(this).val() != "Canada") {
       $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the upvote! for `validates :state, inclusion: { in: %w(usa canada)`, wouldn't this require that the `state` field be either `"usa"` or `"canada"`? I don't think the OP wants these values to be states, but that the `state` field should be populated by an actual state (like `'California"`) if the `country` field is populated by `"usa"` or `"canada"`, hence my validation being on `state` for presence if the `country` is `in?` one of those two.

Comment: Yes that's probably right - it makes more sense than my interpretation. I thought the OP wanted the state to only be USA or Canada